# fw in the user agent

Tags: http, user-agent

one user agent string is:

`mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 6.0; windows nt 5.1; btrs121199; sv1; infopath.1; fw 2.0.6767)`

Does anyone know what `fw 2.0.6767` means?
Does it mean firmware?
Can I change the version easily?

Comment: From where have you extracted that user-agent string?

Comment: from a web log that I need to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, user agent strings don't provide firmware versions unless they are manipulated by users.

The `fw 2.0.6767` fragment present on that UA string may refer to a framework version; Adware or custom fragment added by an application or by the user itself.

---

**Decomposing the [UA string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent):**

> mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 6.0; windows nt 5.1; btrs121199; sv1; infopath.1; fw 2.0.6767)

- `mozilla/4.0`

  Application name and version. For historical reasons, [Internet Explorer identifies itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a Mozilla browser.
- `compatible;`

  Compatibility flag token. It indicates that Internet Explorer is compatible with a set of common features.
- `msie 6.0;`

  The Version token identifies the browser and contains the version number, as reported by the current [browser mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The value indicates Windows Internet Explorer 6.
- `windows nt 5.1;`

  Microsoft Windows NT version 5.1 (commonly known as [Windows XP Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)).
- `btrs121199;`

  *Unknown fragment* <sup>*****</sup>
- `sv1;`

  Windows XP Service Pack 2 installed (Security Version 1)
- `infopath.1;`

  [MS Infopath version 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath) (an MS Office extra application) and means that it may be collecting data for use in a forms based application.
- `fw 2.0.6767`

  *Unknown fragment* <sup>*****</sup>

<sup>*****</sup> May relate to an Adware or a custom identification added by a application being used.

*This is the result that I've been able to compile after 5 hours researching, reading and cross-referencing information.*

---

**Online UA analysis tools:**

You can refer the following websites that provide tons of UA strings, including the fragments identification for any given UA string:

- [User Agent String.Com](http://www.useragentstring.com/)
- [UA string analysis :: user-agent-string.info](http://user-agent-string.info/)
- [User Agent Search - Browser Capabilities Project](http://browsers.garykeith.com/ua-search)

---

**Additional information provided by browser vendors:**

- MDN - [Gecko user agent string reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference)
- MSDN - [Understanding User-Agent Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Opera - [User Agent String](http://my.opera.com/community/openweb/idopera/)